# is "if it's sold out, I can order a copy" can be rewritten in "in the event of book being sold out, I can place an order"?

Tags: grammar, synonyms, writing

I would like to know that the sentence "if it's sold out" can also be "in the event of book being sold out" or "in case of book being sold out"

and the word "order" can be replaced by " place an order" in this situations( in the book stores)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are fine for the most part. You are missing the definite article "the" and some sticklers might harp on the lack of an ***'s*** to show a gerund phrase:

> "In the event (or in case) of ***the* book's** being sold out, I can
>   place an order in the book store."

Now many writers and speakers will seldom put or say the ***'s*** attached to "book" because, first, it sounds stilted and, second, a book is an inanimate object; however, it is correct because "being" is a gerund; therefore, it is acting as a noun therein.  Because it is acting as a noun, the genitive case "book's" should be used.  Again, I just want to reiterate that this is often not followed in speech and writing, however, and when it is followed, it is usually with people and animals:

> "I remember **his** being a lot older."
>
> "**John's** being here is much appreciated."

I hope that might have helped you out.  Take care and good luck!

Comment: wow thanks , then can I use the sentence "in the event of the book that has been sold out" instead of  "in the event of the book being sold out" ?

Comment: No, you can use only "in the event of the book('s) being sold out." The word "if" means "in the event", so you can just change the "of" to "that" and re-create your original statement.

Comment: thank you very much , you're detailed answers really valuable to me

Comment: You're welcome anytime. If you should have any other questions, feel free to ask me.